# How to solve $ x^\top A x = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We could assume $A$ is a positive-definite matrix, if that makes a difference.

How does one solve the equation $x^\top A \; x = 0$ ?

Is there a name to call such an $x$ which is a solution to the above equation?

Comment: I am assuming that $x$ is a real vector. If $A$ is positive definite, we have $x^TAx>0$ for all nonzero $x$. Therefore the only solution is $x=0$.

Comment: If $A$ is positive definite, and $x^tAx=0$, then $x$ must be the zero vector.

Comment: "Is there a name to call such an x which is a solution to the above equation?". Yes there is. It's called a "zero vector".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x$ has to be the zero vector (in $\mathbb{R^n}$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$) as $A$ is positive-definite. This is a different story if $A$ is, say, positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that we are working over the real numbers and that $A$ is non-degenerate to fix ideas.

As said already a few times if $A$ is positive definite (or negative) the only solution is the zero vector.

On the other hand, if $A$ is indefinite it has a signature $(p,q)$ i.e. up to a linear change of variables
$$
{}^txAx=x_1^2+\cdots+x_p^2-y_1^2-\cdots-y_q^2
$$
if $x=(x_1,...,x_p,y_1,...,y_q)$. In this case the set of solutions is what in geometry is called a **cone**: whenever $x$ is a solution also $\lambda x$ is a solution for all $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. In other words, the zero-locus is a set of lines through the origin.

For instance, if the signature is $(1,1)$ the set of solutions is just a pair of lines since
$$
x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)=0
$$
entails $y=\pm x$. If the signature is $(2,1)$, or $(1,2)$, we get the locus
$$
y^2=x_1^2+x_2^2
$$
and this explains the name "cone".

If, instead, we work over the complex numbers the notions of positive definiteness and up to a change of coordinates we are always looking at
$$
z_1^2+\cdots+z_n^2=0
$$
which is never just the zero vector as soon as $n>1$. For instance when $n=2$ we get the two complex lines
$$
z_1=\pm iz_2.
$$
It may be worth remarking that these two lines are the complex lines fixed by the rotations of the real plane and that their points at infinity in the projective extension of the complex plane (called classically "the cyclic points") are the points where all the circles meet the line at infinity.

More convoluted situations happen when we work over fields different from $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. For instance, studying what happens over $\mathbb Q$ may be a good starting point for Number Theory (e.g. Serre's book *Cours d'Arithmetique*)